# angular 4 charjs colors

Tags: angular, charts

couldn't get to work colors in angular 4 chart js. Using "ng2-charts" module.

Markup

```
<div style="display: block">
      <canvas baseChart
              [data]="pieChartData"
              [labels]="pieChartLabels"
              [colors]="chartColors"
              [chartType]="pieChartType"
              (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
              (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Typescript

```
  public pieChartLabels:string[] = ['Download Sales', 'In-Store Sales', 'Mail Sales'];
  public pieChartData:number[] = [300, 500, 100];
  public pieChartType:string = 'pie';
  //  public chartColors:Array<any> = ["#ef9ab2","#7bc6f2","#fce196","#4caf50","#ff5722","#795548","#607d8b","#673ab7","#86d8d8","#9e9e9e",
  //                                      "#e94351","#00bcd4","#fef982","#8e5ea2","#66c855","#fffbdd","#e5e5e5","#f5fdf8","#e8c3b9","#c4574f" 
  //                                     ];
  // public chartColors:Array<any> = [{backgroundColor:"#ef9ab2"},{backgroundColor:"#7bc6f2"},{backgroundColor:"#fce196"}];

// this color range, sets all the pies to same color
public chartColors:Array<any> = [{ 
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(150,12,12,1)',
    borderColor: '#fff',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(150,1,1,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(110,12,12,0.8)'
  },
  { 
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(12,127,152,1)',
    borderColor: '#fff',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(12,17,12,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
  },
  { 
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(12,12,15,1)',
    borderColor: '#fff',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
}];
```

chart generation works fine.  chart doesn't pickup the colors specified.  All 3 pies appears in grey color.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation [here](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/). It would seem that you need to be a bit more specific with your colors. The color object seems to have a number of properties on it that will allow you to control the colors. Depending on how you want your colors to display, you will need to change your colors to something more like the following:

```
public chartColors:Array<any> =
[
    {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    },
    {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    }
];
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it earlier too.  It does picks the first background color for all the pies.    Sorry, i am not sure how to past the code in here(it came out bad), so removed it

Comment: If you have more code to add, update your question and include it there.